# Moving tab title position from top to bottom in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I had to recently moved to Ubuntu 12.04 from 10.04. I am used to see terminal titles in the bottom and prefer the same. Is there some way that I can change the tab title from top to bottom?

Comment: What do you mean by bottom? The bottom of the terminal window or are you thinking of the old panel? Could you illustrate what you want with a screenshot?

Comment: @terdon As I remember how was the terminal interface in 10.04, I think it's about **tab title**. In fact the OP specified this.

Comment: @terdon I want tab titles in the bottom of the default terminal. I cannot produce screenshot of 10.04 as I already moved to 12.04. It is similar the konsole that Radu Radeanu mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I understood that from his comment. Sorry, I've never used a terminal like that so I can't help.

Answer (score 16):

Move to top

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position top
```

Move to bottom

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position bottom
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are using [gnome-terminal](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-terminal/), the default terminal emulator in Ubuntu. In this case, as Elder Geek said in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/432881/147044), I don't think that you have any possibilities to do this.

As alternative, you can use [Konsole](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/konsole/), a terminal emulator built for the KDE Platform, which also works great in Ubuntu and which has exactly the behavior about you asked:

[image: Konsole]

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do this (other than possibly rewriting the source code).

Comment: Yes. It seems like there is no way to do this. I have to train my eyes to search for the tabs at the top of the terminal.

Comment: alternatively you could install Konsole as Radu Rădeanu suggested. Granted the depends are rather extensive (looks like 158 MB on my system)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to move the tab position from the top default to the bottom of the Terminal window in Ubuntu (I have version 18.10)

**gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position bottom**

To move the tabs to the top just issue the same command as above but with top:

**gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position top**